# Set QGIS (on android and/or linux) to use a custom .qgs file by default when opened.

Tags: qgis

Need to have QGIS open with all my settings/layers/projections etc by default.  Created a .qgs file that has all this info in it.  Using Android and Ubuntu.  Tried a shortcut to the .qgs file in android and that didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

The [QGIS guide](http://docs.qgis.org/user_guide/html/en/introduction/features_at_a_glance.html) says:

> Command line option **---project**
>
> Starting QGIS with an existing project file is also possible. Just add the
>   command line option ---project followed by your project name and QGIS will open
>   with all layers loaded described in the given file.

I guess they meant --project.

Does that solve your problem?